# MySQL does not return right data for <= operator

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select date(JoinTime), count(UniqueCallID) from Call2 where JoinTime >= '2016-03-10' and JoinTime <= '2016-03-15' group by day(JoinTime);
```

and the result I get is:

```
| date(JoinTime) | count(distinct UniqueCallID) |
+----------------+------------------------------+
| 2016-03-10     |                           20 |
| 2016-03-11     |                           29 |
| 2016-03-12     |                            2 |
| 2016-03-13     |                            5 |
| 2016-03-14     |                           12 |
```

As you can see it has not returned data for 2016-03-15, even though I clearly set the `>=` operator as I wanted to include 2016-03-15.

I've also tried with BETWEEN like this:

```
select date(JoinTime), count(UniqueCallID) from Call2 where JoinTime between '2016-03-10' and '2016-03-15' group by day(JoinTime);
```

and the result was the same.

Why does this happen? And what can I do to fix it?

Comment: What data type is `JoinTime`?

Comment: Why you use `DATE()` function then?

Comment: provide raw data source please

Comment: Then mmm has the right answer. The reason the entries for the 15th are not being returned is that '2016-03-15 10:34:22' IS greater than '2016-03-15'. The easiest solution is to make it `< '2016-03-16'`, but without changing the constraints the cast will get you what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are only comparing to dates, you need to CAST `JoinTime` to a date first

```
select date(JoinTime), count(UniqueCallID) 
from Call2 where date(JoinTime) between '2016-03-10' and '2016-03-15' 
group by day(JoinTime);
```

Also, as there might be several months relevant, you should group by year, month and day:

```
select date(JoinTime), count(UniqueCallID) 
from Call2 where date(JoinTime) between '2016-03-10' and '2016-03-15'     
group by year(JoinTime), month(JoinTime), day(JoinTime);
```

---

The way you are using it, an entry like

```
2016-03-15 12:21:32
```

will be checked against

```
2016-03-15 00:00:00
```

so it will not be included as it doesn't match the `<=` condition.

Answer (score 3):

If JoinTime is of type DateTime and you don't provide a 'time' part, MySql assumes that your time is midnight ('2016-03-10 00:00:00'). So you are checking from '2016-03-10 00:00:00' to '2016-03-15 00:00:00' which gives your result.

Try a day later, or cast to date how mmm provided.